# referencing a sheet which has a space in its name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference, formula, formulas

I have a following formula which is refencing Sheet2:

```
((COUNTIF((INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&ADDRESS(ROW(Sheet2!J4);COLUMN(Sheet2!J4))&":J"& 
(MIN(IF(Sheet2!A4:A107="";ROW(Sheet2!A4:A107))))));"<>"&""))-1)
```

When i want to change the name of "Sheet2" to "Deployment Plan" and adjust the formula to formula below, it gives an referance error.

```
((COUNTIF((INDIRECT("DeploymentPlan!"&ADDRESS(ROW(Sheet2!J4);
COLUMN(Sheet2!J4))&":J"& (MIN(IF(Sheet2!A4:A107="";ROW(Sheet2!A4:A107))))));"<>"&""))-1)
```

I am pretty sure that this error is happening because there is a blank in my new sheet name "Deployment Plan".

How can i adjust my formula so it works correct?

Comment: Use single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap the name of the worksheet in single quotes (`''`):

```
((COUNTIF((INDIRECT("'Deployment Plan'!"&ADDRESS(ROW('Deployment Plan'!J4);
COLUMN('Deployment Plan'!J4))&":J"& (MIN(IF('Deployment Plan'!A4:A107="";ROW('Deployment Plan'!A4:A107))))));"<>"&""))-1)
```